# How do you delete a Heroku data clip?

Tags: heroku

I created a [Heroku data clip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips), and now I don't want it any more.  I can't find a delete button.  Help?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found it in the drop-down next to "Save & Run".

[image]